# How to sort by different lines in one column?

Tags: tablesorter

For my work I need to add specific sorting for one column of a table. Here is a table:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Simple sort 1</th>
            <th>Simple sort 2</th>
            <th>Complex sort 3.1<br/>Complex sort 3.2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>ccc<br/>333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aab</td>
        <td>bbc</td>
        <td>ccd<br/>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aac</td>
        <td>bbd</td>
        <td>cce<br/>111</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Table example existing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHkvl.png)

It should be possible to sort either by "Complex sort 3.1" or by "Complex sort 3.2" and it should look similar to this:

[Table example desirable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c57A1.png)

Please advice how to achieve it with tablesorter?

**UPDATE**

Now I should sort by **price** in one line and by **date** in another

```html
<tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>
        10,15 EUR
        <br/>
        15.09.2017
    </td>
</tr>
```

So I updated my code to detect date and force date sorting over sortNatural. And I wanted to just return somme dateSorter etc.

What should it be?

```js
textSorter: {
    ".multiline-sort": function (a, b, direction, columnIndex, table) {
        if ($cell) {
            var i = $cell.filter('.active').attr('data-index');
            if (i || i === 0) {
                var x = a.split('\u200C'),// &zwnj; used as delimiter
                    y = b.split('\u200C');
                var isDateRegex = /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/;
                if (isDateRegex.test(x[i])) {
                    return $.tablesorter.DATESORTER($.trim(x[i]), $.trim(y[i])); // ????? HERE I WANT TO SORT AS DATE
                }
                return $.tablesorter.sortNatural($.trim(x[i]), $.trim(y[i]));
            }
        }
        return $.tablesorter.sortNatural(a, b);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [tablesorter (fork) wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki) are a bunch of demos. One of which is this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/s72h56wn/

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
              <span class="sort" data-index="0">Data 1</span> | 
              <span class="sort" data-index="1">Data 2</span> | 
              <span class="sort" data-index="2">Data 3</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Text 1 | Text H | Data 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text 3 | Text F | Data 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text 2 | Text G | Data 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text 5 | Text B | Data 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text 8 | Text E | Data 6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text 6 | Text C | Data 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text 7 | Text D | Data 8</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Text 9 | Text A | Data 7</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(function () {

    var $cell;
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textSorter: function (a, b) {
            var x = a.split('|'),
                y = b.split('|'),
                i = $cell.filter('.active').attr('data-index');
            return $.tablesorter.sortNatural($.trim(x[i]), $.trim(y[i]));
        },
        initialized: function () {
            $cell = $('table thead th').find('span');
            $cell.click(function () {
                // activate percentage sort
                $(this)
                  .addClass('active')
                  .siblings()
                  .removeClass('active');
                return false;
            });

        }
    });

});
```

**Note:** Some of the demos on that wiki page don't appear to work, that's because the jQuery version is set to "edge". Change it to jQuery v3.3.1 and it'll start working.

---

**Update**

New demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/jgdx23st/

HTML

```
<th class="multiline-sort">
  <span class="sort" data-index="0">Price</span> |
  <span class="sort active" data-index="1">Date</span>
</th>
```

JS

```
$(function() {

  function reverseDate(date) {
    return date.split('.').reverse().join('.');
  }

    var $spans;
  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    textSorter: {
      '.multiline-sort': function(a, b, direction, columnIndex, table) {
        var i = $spans.filter('.active').attr('data-index'),
          // using a tab &#x9; in the HTML to separate the content
          x = $.trim(a.split('\u0009')[i]),
          y = $.trim(b.split('\u0009')[i]),
          valx = i == 1 ? reverseDate(x) : x,
          valy = i == 1 ? reverseDate(y) : y;
        return $.tablesorter.sortNatural(valx, valy);
      },
    },
    initialized: function() {
      $spans = $('table thead .multiline-sort .sort');
      $spans.on('click', function() {
        $spans.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        return false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I saw this demo but didn't understand that this solution is right for me. It works great.

Comment: $.tablesorter.sortNatural works great for text, numbers etc. But what about dates? First line of my multiline cell is money amount "47,45 EUR‌" (which sorts great) and second line is date "29.10.2015" (which sorts like text). How to achieve date sorting in my multiline situation?

Comment: You can't expect every date format to work correctly out of the box. However if you used the format `YYYY.MM.DD` it would sort as expected. You can accomplish this by adding one of the available date parsers or by adding the `YYYY.MM.DD` format into the `data-text` attribute of the cell. See https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textattribute

Comment: Updated my answer. Next time, please ask a more specific question first, e.g. sorting price & date versus generic sorting. It would have saved both you and me a lot of time.